# Long-running PHP script running out of memory

Tags: php, memory, memory-management

I have a PHP script whose job it is to take data from one database, row by row, do something with it, and write it to a different database.  There will be about 800,000 rows in all (and will take more than a day to run).  I monitor the memory usage as it's running, and the memory usage seems to go up about 10k for every row added, and I run out of memory before I even get to 10,000 rows.  I have no idea why anything is staying in memory, I limit my import to 5,000 rows, and before I exit the program I NULL all the variables and do another memory check and it doesn't go down at all.  If the variables aren't using the memory, what is?  How can I fix it?

Comment: Are you using mysqli or PDO?

Comment: Show us the script and we can help you rewrite it

Comment: Telepathy offline, please post code.

Answer (score 1):

Did you tried instead of setting the `var` to NULL, `unset()` it?

---

Anyway, I think is better if you follow a different approach.

Probably your issue can be solved with [PHP generators (yields)](https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.generators.syntax.php).

```php
<?php

declare(strict_types=1);

// In case you are using mysqli driver:
function mysqliGenerator(mysqli_result $res)
{
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res)) {
        yield $row;
    }
}


$result = $mysqli->query("SELECT ...");
foreach (mysqliGenerator($result) as $row)
{
    var_dump($row);
}
```

```php
// In case you are using PDO driver:
function pdoGenerator(PDOStatement $statement)
    while ($row = $statement->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))  {
        yield $row;
    }
}

$statement = $pdo->query('SELECT ...');
foreach (pdoGenerator($statement) as $row) {
    var_dump($row);
}
```

Comment: I've been setting the `var` to NULL, as that's what I saw others had recommended for freeing memory.  I do use PDO, but not the generator... you think that saves memory rather than going without it?

Comment: @DanGoodspeed, that's strange. I never face a situation similar as you described. It is supposed `null` should work, anyway, generators in PHP are designed for this kind of scenarios (getting large data from a stream like a file or a DB). There is a lot of information about `yield`s in PHP, google it to understand better how they are implemented and working!